# Passing argument of type Double using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection in a situation where I need to pass in arguments that have a type Double. My code works perfectly when I call the function directly, but it fails when I do it via reflection with two doubles as its arguments. Here is the eror:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jinstagram.Instagram.searchMedia(java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double)`

```
Double lat = Double.parseDouble(methodArgument[0][0]);
Double lng = Double.parseDouble(methodArgument[0][1]);
Method m = instagram.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("searchMedia", Double.class, Double.class);
Object o = (Object) m.invoke(instagram, lat, lng);
```

Just for testing, I can call this successfully like this:

```
Object o = instagram.searchMedia(lat, lng);
```

so the problem must be somewhere in the use of reflection, right?

Comment: how org.jinstagram.Instagram.searchMedia(java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double) looks like?

Comment: Provide your "searchMedia" method signature in your question.

Comment: If it takes a `double` rather than a `Double`, you can use `double.class`.  (Note capitalization)

Comment: Ack! That was it. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the method in question is

```
public MediaFeed searchMedia(double latitude, double longitude)
                                                             throws InstagramException
```

So you need to use `double.class` instead of `Double.class`

Comment: Credit where due, this possibility was pointed out by @Pokechu22 while I was writing my answer.